# Find the difference between current time and last failure in grafana?

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

I have a dashboard built up where i am able to fetch the last failure time through conditions such as (total_failed<>0) but that gives me output as time like 10:20 but I need to have the Output generated in form of "last failed 30 mins ago " by calculating (current time - failure time ) so that. I can show that in dashboard .
Query Given -

```
    SELECT
  end_time AS "time",
  
  (total_failed::integer)
FROM job
where
  total_failed<>'0'
GROUP BY end_time,total_failed
```

Let me know if anyone can help me writing that sql or representation of that dashboard .

Comment: Your code certainly looks like Postgres, and, if so, then please remove the other non compatible database tags.

Comment: Surely done but can u help me wirh the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this combination of `age`, `extract` and a CTE is what you need:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT age(clock_timestamp(), end_time) AS ago,
           total_failed::integer AS fail_count
    FROM job
    WHERE ...
)
SELECT extract(minutes FROM ago)
          + 60 * extract(hours FROM ago) AS minutes_passed,
       fail_count
FROM data;
```